# I cant set a background-image to a specific div or body

Tags: css

I'm trying to set a background image for the site I'm building. I know I have to use `background: url();` but it doesn't seem to show up whether its in `body` or a specific `div`.

```css
body {
    /* background: linear-gradient(#2c3e50 75%, #ecf0f1 88%); */
    background: url(c:\Users\Saleh\Desktop\Abid\ggbridge960.png);
} /* This is is what it looks like when I add it to body */

.container {
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    /* border: 2px solid black; */
    width: 960px;
    height: 1000px;
    /* background: url(c:\Users\Saleh\Desktop\Abid\ggbridge960.png) no-repeat; */
} /* this is what it looks like in the div. */
```

I've tried them both separately not simultaneously.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery or HTML?

Comment: can you try with a relative path or use the `file://` protocol suffix like `url(file://c:/Users/Saleh/Desktop/Abid/ggbridge960.png)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this..

```
body {
 background: url(file:///c:/Users/Saleh/Desktop/Abid/ggbridge960.png);
}
```

Comment: Actually, it needs to have the property name, so `background-image:url(file://...)` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image:url(images/your_image.png);
width:960px;
height:1000px;
```

should do the trick :)

Maybe you have a div ahead which is hidden it ?

To make it simple at the beginning you could also try to give a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

- Make sure the image file exists by entering the file path in your browser (c:\Users\Saleh\Desktop\Abid\ggbridge960.png)
- If you're linking to the css file from the HTML, make sure it's linked correctly by adding an obvious style to the container and checking whether it gets applied.
- Use this syntax:

  ```
  body {background-image:url('c:\Users\Saleh\Desktop\Abid\ggbridge960.png');}
  ```
- also noticed that you're using back-slashes instead of forward slashes -  maybe try:

  ```
  c:/Users/Saleh/Desktop/Abid/ggbridge960.png
  ```